# Why isn't the history of mechanics dated from Archimedes time?

Tags: mathematics, physics, ancient-greece, classical-mechanics

It's often said - and more often written - and perhaps, even more spoken of - that modern physics began with Galileo due to his application of mathematics to motion. This is the position taken by Einstein in his semi-popular book on the evolution of physics with Infield. Whereas motion had been theorised before, it was Galileos paradigm-shattering idea to quantify motion and hence discover actual quantitative relationships between the various factors of motion, that is distance, mass, speed and acceleration.

However, more broadly speaking mathematics had been applied much earlier in mechanics. For example, Archimedes law of the lever. And although I haven't checked, I expect that Hero of Alexandria had a quantitative idea of how block and tackle pulleys worked.

Thus, the key paradigmatic idea that separates the Renaissance of mechanics in 16th C Italy and the Hellenic Greece of Antiquity seems not be as paradigmatic as one might suppose.

**Q. Why then the focus, as exemplified by Einstein, on the history of mechanics or physics as beginning in Renaissance Europe, when the evidence points to a much broader and historically, much longer period of time?**

Comment: Archimedes did not quantify motion, the mechanics he applied geometry to was statics, which was enough to explain the work of simple machines. Histories of statics do often start with Archimedes, but the dynamics of the time, Aristotle's, was qualitative. Nor did Archimedes suggest extracting those quantitative relationships from experiments.

Comment: Einstein and Infeld were concerned with dynamics, for this reason they start with Galileo. Dynamics is not the whole mechanics: there is also statics (including hydrostatics), which really originated in antiquity, more precisely in the Hellenistic age.  Einstein and Infeld is a popular book, which address only a part of the history of physics.

Comment: @Conifold: The point I'm making is the question of applying mathematics to physics and this includes static or equilibria phenomena. Presumably the application of mathematics to mechanics  had to wait until appropriate methods of timing with enough precision were developed so as to gauge the physical values of interest - like speed and acceleration. Dynamics in this ense is a much more delicate affair than statics, where experiments as well as observations are easier.

Answer (score 3):

Dugas’ [History of Mechanics (French ed 1958)](https://books.google.it/books?id=kdDDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) starts with Aristotle followed by Archimedes.

Then Hellenistic and Arabic science, followed by Middle Age and Renaissance.

Thus it is old but quite comprehensive.

Comment: The question opens with "often said and more often written" and the title asks about Archimedes. It might be misleading or incorrect etc.  Galileo famously started by demolishing Aristotle.

Comment: @sand1: This is how we see it - it's not how Galileo saw it. In the same way, we might say Einstein demolished Newton. He would have said he simply took Newton and Maxwell seriously. Likewise with the early pioneers of mechanics in the modern era - they took Aristotle seriously. For example, the SEP says quite [accurately](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/galileo/), 'Galileo subjected Aristotle to critique in his 1590 manuscript, *De Motu*' - this is how science progresses.

Comment: The question is a plausible generalization so just one counter example is not an answer.

Comment: @sand1 - good books start from the beginning. Modern “science of motion” starts with Galileo... but in order to understand it we have to know Renaissance science of mechanics, as well as Medieval one and Arstotle physics and Archimedes.

Answer (score 1):

Because otherwise historians had to admit that Christianity, by destroying the ancient civilization, caused a regress. Even if after the fall of the Roman Empire the population experienced some relief, ultimately the whole Western world stagnated and sunk culturally. Quantitative data is available through Ian Morris project (*Why the West Rules - For now*, 2010 and [additional material](https://web.archive.org/web/20120330231438/http://www.ianmorris.org/docs/social-development.pdf)). The renewed  access to Aristotle, it is universally admitted, caused a ["medieval renaissance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance_of_the_12th_century) which is a further proof that the general intellectual level has become lower than 1500 years ago. The whole catastrophic cultural episode brought by church ideology has been denied by religiously minded historians but also by marxists who insisted that history *is progress*.

Comment: I doubt it. Blaming Christianity for the Dark Ages was the refrain of Enlightenment (and the Barbarian Invasions probably had no less to do with it, if not more), and they were more than happy to trace their lineage to ancient Greeks, as do many modern authors like Einstein or Sagan. But Greeks simply did not have either quantitative dynamics or experimental approach of modern mechanics, so they are more of a pre-history there.

Comment: The s.c. "scientific revolution" (XVIIc.) icluded the vigorous  bashing of Aristotle but actually it was a push against church authorities who backed him. Galileo's *Dialogue* berates Aristotle while praising Archimedes. The question appears to have some grounds.

Comment: Many historians already do, to a certain extent, when they report on the fate of Hypatia.